# Ordering a list of NSStrings in NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

Is it possible to order an NSMutableArray where it's values are NSStrings? I'm looking to order alphabetically. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
NSMutableArray* stringsArray;
...
[stringsArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Comment: Or `caseInsensitiveCompare:` if you want to ignore case.